# How can i calculate Vs in this circuit knowing Vo=2?

Tags: voltage

[image]

I know that using Ohm Law i can calculate the I  of the 2k resistance:
I  = V/R <=> I= 1*10^(-3)<=> I = 1mA

But i dont know what to do after , i've tried using Kirchhoff voltage law and the voltage divider formula but i cant get it right.
(Supposedely from my appointments the answer is 24V but i dont know how to get there, thanks for any help).

Comment: Do you know that the 4k resistor current is also equal to 1mA?

Comment: @G36 actually no, everything i've learned was from google and wikipedia so i have lots of lacks of knowledge in this subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So try to remember this.

And the **I Kirchhoff's law** (KCL)

[image]

And the **II Kirchhoff's law** (KVL)

[image]

Notice that form KVL we have **V2 + V3 = V4** (components in a parallel circuit share the same voltage)

[image]

1 - Components in a series circuit share the same current **I**.

2 - Total voltage in a series circuit is equal to the sum of the individual voltage drops

**VB = V1 + V2**.

Comment: Wow this thing took me way to much time to solve, thanks for your explanation...if you dont mind i have another question that is, the current starts on the Vs thing right? If so whats the objective of the + - on the right side,  is that 2 sources of energy? Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: Yes, the current starts at positive voltage source terminal.  https://obrazki.elektroda.pl/8358373700_1507399570.png     And this  + - on the right side of a 2k resistor indicates the voltage polarity across this 2k resistor.  The author assumes that the current is flowing from the "top" to the bottom. So, the voltage at the "top" is higher. Because the voltage is a kind of "electrical height". Try read this http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~jstiles/312/handouts/312_Introduction_package.pdf start reading from page 3.

Answer (score 1):

As you found the current flowing through the 2k resistor is 1mA, so it means that the same current flows through the 4k resistor. This helps find the voltage drop across the two resistors. Now you know(I hope so) the voltage across the 6k resistor. Use that to find the current flowing through it. Then use KCL to figure out the current going through 9k resistor. Now that you have found the currents apply KVL to get the unknown voltage Vs. I think I gave you more than enough hints.

Answer (score 0):

Take steps one at a time. You computed the current through the 2K resistor.

The next hint is that the same current is through the 4K resistor. Use that hint to find the voltage in total across the 4K and 2K.

The second hint I'll give is that the voltage across the 6K is same as that from just above.

Several more steps are necessary so keep an eye on where currents come from and/or what voltages are present as you calculate.