# In a basic Ohm's Law circuit, is the effect of the resistor localized?

Tags: resistors, ohms-law

[image]

Elaborate way to put my question: Why is the current before the resistor and after the resistor same?

Since I'm taking beginner taking classes about electricity, this is what I know about circuits.

The series circuit about what I understand about them, is that we have a battery with positive and negative terminal, allowing the flow of electrons between them, is what we take advantage of by connecting a wire and add other components like a bulb and that flow of electrons (current) which supplies them energy along the way. It's like adding a wire between 2 charged objects ( one positive and one negative.) To me, resistors would control the amount of current flowing through the circuit.

My view: If there were electrons flowing at x amperes and they suddenly reach a resistor they would take time to flow through that decreasing the current, but this is not true. Why not?

It would be helpful if someone could solve this.

Comment: It's not clear what the question here is. Do you understand what a voltmeter does? (it measures the potential difference between two points. So, how you connect it directly follows from what you want to measure. The way it's connected here, what you want to measure is a potential between the two contacts. So that can't be modified without changing what you measure.)

Comment: Heat produced by the resistor is not localized - if it were it would continue to warm until it burnt out.

Comment: If you don't need to read the voltage, the voltmeter in parallel is not necessary.

Comment: Any simple resistor (including this resistor) has 2 endpoint connections (nodes.) Everything that occurs between these 2 nodes will always obey Ohm's Law. Unless the circuit is travelling at the speed of light.

Comment: @Sam Gibson , Thanks , I've just posted the re-edit , even though there might be a similar question out there , the answers did not quite convince me of the fact that current before and after the resistor is the same

Comment: That is like saying you're not convinced water flow before and after the pipe is the same. Do you feel the resistor  stores some charge internally when current flows? @AarushiAgarwal

Comment: @SamGibson , Hi :) , I actually do understand why and how a resistor works , I understood it yesterday , But I was hoping for a more comprehensive answers which help me gain more of other's Povs on how to approach this ....... And Btw im a highschooler taking classes

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/511363/voltage-drop-across-a-single-resistor-and-across-two-resistors/511367#511367

Comment: @AarushiAgarwal - Hi, Just to summarise: Now that you have added a much clearer and more specific question into the text, I have reopened it so it is available to be answered. I also removed earlier comments which had become obsolete, now that the question has been improved.

Answer (score 6):

Current is simply the flow of charges.

Why is the current before the resistor and after the same? Because the resistor is unable to store any extra charges. When any charge enters on one side of the resistor, it pushes another one out on the other side, so that the total number of mobile charges in the resistor remains unchanged.

But you are right that resistors impede the flow of current. If you remove a resistor from a circuit and replace the resistor with a wire, much higher current will flow.

Answer (score 4):

Ah, you've hit the grade-school misconception that "current" flows in wires  ...and that wires are like hollow pipes. The power-supply must fill the pipes ...so how can it possibly know about the resistances, before any of the electricity has even arrived there?

All wrong.   It's one of those huge lies told to little kids, like gravity in space being zero, or tongues having "flavor zones."  Electrons flow at lightspeed inside wires.  Didn't you know that human blood is bright blue like paint?  The blood in you veins?  Heh.

Instead, currents are *flows of charge*, where amperes are just a rate, the couloumbs/sec.  "Charge" flows in wires, not amps, and all conductors are MADE of charge:  movable charge.   Mobile electrons.   All metals contain an "electron sea," as if they were little tanks of electricity.  Any chunk of metal is like a jar full of water, with no dirt-specks to make any flows visible.  All wires are like little pre-filled pipes with no bubbles allowed.  Together, these things form the "hydraulic analogy" used for explaining circuits ever since Oliver Lodge originally invented it for his 1890s physics classroom.

So, a circuit is a closed hydraulic loop, behaving much like a bicycle wheel, where the rubber tire is the electrons.  (Heh, closed hydraulic loops are way too arcane for beginners, so the analogy *of the* hydraulic analogy is the bike-wheel, or the rubber drive-belt.)

Push on the mobile electrons at any point in a circuit, and the entire loop of electrons begins moving, turning as one.   Then, a resistor is like your thumb dragging on the bicycle tire (it will slow the entire tire down, if nothing else is keeping it going.)   Resistors are "friction points" on the electron-loop.   In a flashlight, the bulb is like that dragging thumb, while the battery is your hand that applies constant sideways pressure, causing the whole tire to rotate at constant rate, depending on how hard the thumb is dragging.  Mechanical Ohm's Law, for the Upside-down Bicycle.

Here's a physics edu. paper about all that stuff:
[Chabay and Sherwood 2001, "A unified treatment...](https://matterandinteractions.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/circuit.pdf)
Circuits are actually based on static electricity (heh, grade school has lied to us yet again.)

My large list of [grade-school electricity misconceptions](http://amasci.com/miscon/elect.html) (scroll down there.)

Also: my [collected essays on "Electricity."](http://amasci.com/ele-edu.html)   What *IS* electricity?

For books, try Amdahl's THERE ARE NO ELECTRONS electronics for earthlings, also Ashby's ELECTRICAL ENGINEERING 101: things you should have learned in school but probably didn't

---

Circuits are also like rubber drive belts, where a generator is like a drive-wheel, and chains of resistors  in series are like several dragging fingers: ...friction-points arraigned in series.

With drive belts, why is the speed of the belt always the same going into the fan-pulley, as the belt-speed on the other side?   After all, the fan is a load, a relatively huge "resistor!"   Don't fans *consume rubber?*  This is taught by every grade-school science book!  It can't possibly be wrong, can it?   The drive wheel creates rubber, the rubber zooms to the fan at the speed of light, then the fan uses it up.  That's essentially what we all were taught.  Electricity flows in closed "circuits."   And also, electricity is a form of energy.  The light bulb consumes the electricity.  So why does the all the electricity have to flow back to the flashlight batteries?!!!  It just makes no sense.  (That's because it's wrong.   In engineering school these misconceptions are never corrected.  Instead we just learn the proper math-models.  Then we cannot visualize what's happening inside the wires.  No intuitive grasp!  We can only visualize what our DMMs would read, if we connect them to our visualized schematics.)

[image: Exploratorium exhibit: Pacific Gas and Leath]

Here's an exhibit at "The Exploratorium" museum in San Francisco.  **[P. G. and L., Pacific Gas and Leather.](http://annex.exploratorium.edu/xref/exhibits/pacific_gas_&_leather.html)**   This one was actually created by the late museum founder, physicist Frank Oppenheimer, a physics educator who was well aware of all the garbage being taught by K12-grade science books.  He's using his museum to attack the misconceptions.   "Electricity" in circuits is like all those leather drive-belts in an 1800s factory.  Electric companies don't sell any leather, instead they only sell us some invisible "work" which travels through the belts at extremely high speed.  That's the physics viewpoint, where "electricity" comes in coulombs, and inside circuits, it flows very slowly in closed circles, without any being created or destroyed.  Frank's exhibit even inclused a FW bridge rectifier, mechanical ratchets, where the AC supply (wiggling leather) is converted into a "direct current" to spin the little fan blades.  Visible electricity!  Sheers genius.  Some of those physicists were actually smart.  (But not politically savvy, and when RP Feynman tried to correct some K6 textbooks, the problem whipped him so badly, he had to flee in terror, before it destroyed his sanity, or at least his marriage.)  From "Surely you're joking...", [Judging Books By Their Covers.](http://amasci.com/miscon/feynjudg.html)   Today the problem seems even worse.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is actually interesting if I understand you correctly.  Using the water analogy that a commenter on your question referenced.

As I understand, you are asking about the initial front of electrons "hitting" the resistor like an empty Riverbed suddenly filling with water snd approaching a restriction.  The first edge of water goes right through (even accelerates) as the riverbed constricts. Only after the riverbed is flowing with a steady state of water does the constriction slow the average volume of water going through.

So, to be clear, electricity is way different. There is no empty riverbed that fills with electrons. The voltage source has to push all of the existing electrons through like a long swamp suddenly being tilted ever so slightly and caused to flow.  And "each" electron interacting with the conductor's (conductive band/metallic bonds/any model you wish to imagine) as they move through the circuit.

Answer (score 0):

> My view: If there were electrons flowing at x amperes and they
> suddenly reach a resistor they would take time to flow through that
> decreasing the current, **but this is not true**. Why not?

But it *is* true, and is exactly how resistors reduce current.

You have to remember that a conductor has a 'sea' of free electrons in it *all the time*, constantly moving around at many different velocities (speed *and* direction) with an average speed of about 1/300th the speed of light. But since they are moving in all different directions their average velocities sum to zero. When a voltage is applied these electrons *drift* down the wire at a much lower velocity, at the same time as they are whizzing around in all different directions.

Current is the measure of the *number* of charges passing a particular point in a unit of time. It says nothing about the velocity of individual electrons. 1 amp is 1 [coulomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb) of charge per second, or ~6.24 x 10<sup>18</sup> electrons per second. That could be 6.24 x 10<sup>18</sup> single electrons racing down a very thin wire one after the other, or trillions of them lazily wandering down a fat wire alongside each other. The thicker the wire, the slower they need to go to make up the numbers.

Now consider what happens if you have a nice fat wire with electrons drifting down it at low velocity, and you 'suddenly' make part of the wire much narrower. Now the electrons are crowded closer together making them more likely to 'bump into' other particles that cause them to lose kinetic energy and slow down. That means the current is lower, and the electrons in the fatter part *also* have to slow down because they have nowhere else to go.

That narrow piece of wire is your 'resistor'. For a given current the individual electrons in the thin wire are moving *faster* than the electrons in the fatter wires. That causes them to have more collisions, lose more energy and heat the wire up more. But while the speed of electrons may be different in different parts of a series circuit, the current is the same in all parts because every electron is 'pushing' another one ahead of it, with any gaps being immediately filled by other electrons coming in from behind.

Some materials have higher intrinsic resistance than others, allowing the creation of high resistance values without having to use extremely thin and/or long wires. A carbon composite resistor is typically fatter than the wires it is connected to, so the drift velocity of electrons in it is *slower* than in the wires because its cross-sectional area is larger.

But for electrical analysis we don't care about that. All we need to know is how much current is flowing, and that the 'resistor' follows [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law). Real resistors also have capacitance and inductance, but for analysis we model these properties as separate components. So when you see a resistor in a theoretical circuit, that is *all* it is. You don't have be concerned about what the electrons in it are doing. You don't have to consider what happens when they 'suddenly' reach a resistor, because it is assumed to occur 'instantly'.

In reality nothing happens instantly, because nothing can move faster than the speed of light. Electrons are pushed around the circuit by electric and magnetic fields, which travel as a wave around the wires. At high frequencies we need to account for that, which we do using capacitance, inductance, and transmission line theory. But what is 'high' depends on the situation - 50 Hz is 'low' in house wiring, but not in a 3,000 km long transmission line. At DC and 'low' frequencies where the current goes around the circuit 'instantly' all this can be ignored, which makes circuit analysis a lot easier.