# Current through combination of parallel and series resistors

Tags: current, resistors, current-divider

I have created a simple example in order to understand what is going on with the current through combination of resistors (parallel and in series) in a electrical circuit. I ask my self to calculate the current through resistor R3.

[image]

R1 is in parallel with R2 (R1||R2) and R2 in series with R3.So $$R_{eq} = \frac{5*4}{5+4}+R3 = \frac{20}{9}+8=\frac{92}{9} \approx 10.222$$.

Now the current that flows through R1 is (I use the current division here):

$$ i_{1} = \frac{i}{R_1}\left(\frac{R1*R2}{R1+R2}\right) =  i\left(\frac{R2}{R1+R2}\right) =\frac{16}{3}=5.333 $$

for i_2

$$ i_{2} = \frac{i}{R_2}\left(\frac{R1*R2}{R1+R2}\right) =  i\left(\frac{R1}{R1+R2}\right) =\frac{60}{9}=6.666 $$

Both currents i_1 and i_2 add up to the current that the source is giving to the circuit.And now because R3 is in series with R2 the current is the same for R3. Am I correct here? Or I am missing something?

**Edit**

[image]

Comment: All 3 are in parallel. Label your junctions and all 3 resistors are connected to both junctions.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I made an edit in the picture in OR but explain me why R3 is in parallel? I would appreciate it.

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson They are still all in parallel. Rotate and move R3 next to R2 and you'll see. All three resistors connect one terminal to one node, and other terminal to the orher node. There are only two nodes. DEFGH are same node and ABC are same node. If you think R2 is in series with R3, you should explain why you think they are, because they aren't.

Comment: If a wire connects the junctions, they are the same junction.  A junction has 3 or more wires.  A, B and C are the same junction.

Comment: @Justme why?how can I say according to junctions if two resistors are in parallel or not?

Comment: The current's going from A to H.  It can go through A, B, R1, G, H.  And A, B, C, R2, F, G, H.  And A, B, C, R3, D, E, F, G, H.  It never goes through two resistors, so none of them can be in series.

Comment: @SimonB thank you for the clarification.I added another picture.Tell me if I am correct this time.

Comment: Two ways. If you can leave one side of a resistor and go through wires to another resistor AND leave the second and go back to the first.  Second, two or more resistors share two junctions.  With a junction being 3 or more wires.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat now I lost you.Your previous comment was much more helpful.

Comment: Take a look here it may help you https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/511363/voltage-drop-across-a-single-resistor-and-across-two-resistors/511367#511367

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson it's definitely a mixture of series and parallel in the 2nd picture.

Comment: Your 1st pic and your 2nd pic are entirely different circuits. For example, in your 1st pic D, E & F are all the same node - they're joined by wires. In your 2nd pic you've grouped D % E with C, and separated F off to a different node.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *R1 is in parallel with R2 (R1||R2) and R2 in series with R3*

No, that is incorrect; all three are in parallel.

> *Am I correct here? Or I am missing something?*

The latter.

Answer (score 2):

Learn to redraw schematics:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvjApM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That's all it is that you have.

First, get the least common multiple of those numbers, which is 40. Use that  and replace all those resistors with their whole-number conductances: \$S_1=\frac{40}5=8\$, \$S_2=\frac{40}4=10\$, and \$S_3=\frac{40}8=5\$. Sum those up to get \$S=23\$. Then the proportion of \$I_1\$ that each gets is \$\frac{S_1}{S}=\frac8{23}\$, \$\frac{S_2}{S}=\frac{10}{23}\$, and \$\frac{S_3}{S}=\frac5{23}\$.

You could use nodal and solve for the unknown voltage of that top wire and then compute the current in \$R_3\$, too.

(The Rank-Nullity Theorem explains exactly why there's no need to connect the other side of \$I_1\$ to anything and why there's no need to separately do KCL for the ground node. In fact, the mathematics won't work if you do write KCL for ground. But that's another topic.)