Application of Kirchhoff's voltage law to a section of a circuit
I have to write an equation for calculating value of current on the circuit section. Let's say that direction of bypassing the circuit was chosen the same as direction of current on the figure. I tried this equation, but I don't sure especially with potential difference. Shouldn't it be it be φ1 - φ2?
φ2 - φ1 + E5 - E4 - E3 - E2 - E1 = IR4 + IR3 + IR2 + IR1

Voltage sources on the figure are presented by power sources. E5 corresponds to the direction of the current, other sources are inverted.

Your, equation is wrong. How can you say that Voltage equals Current? This is wrong. Current is a different thing than voltage. Also in your circuit, all components are connected in series. Therefore only one current (the same current) can flow in this circuit through the components.  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/511363/voltage-drop-across-a-single-resistor-and-across-two-resistors/511367#511367

I’m voting to close this question because the shown circuit is impossible – a row of contradicting current sources can't exist. And the text is sadly not even remotely related to how linear electric networks work, so I'm afraid there's nothing to salvage here.

@MarcusMüller "post-Soviet" notation of electric circuit symbols is used here. I should have mention that. In this way, it is really voltage source (EMF).

Ah thanks! then I'm voting to reopen

The symbols used for voltage sources are actually current sources. Current sources in series don't make sense. So I will treat them as voltage sources. It is not clear what Kirchhoff's second law is. You need to apply Kirchhoff's voltage law here, to be clear.
Elements in series may be interchanged if the polarities remain consistent, like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I have used different values but the re-arrangement is clear. The voltage symbols are proper with the polarities for the KVL path indicated with the numbers. The ground is included to provide a point of reference for \$\phi 1\$ and \$\phi 2\$. You should be able to make the equation from here.

Yes, thank you. It must be Kirchhoff's voltage law. I think equation that I wrote is right, but I am not sure about potential difference. Maybe it should be left ϕ1 - ϕ2.

Or $\phi_2-\phi_1$ depending on the KVL direction. @ArturKrush. Set the polarity to match the chosen KVL direction.. Be clear that those voltage polarities are negative with reference to ground. But one is positive with respect tp the KVL path. So be careful to get the polarities consistent. My $\phi_1=-2V $ while $\phi_2=-1V $ measured to ground. In performing the clockwise KVL sum, $\phi_2=+1V $ while $\phi_1=-2V $. Remember that the polarity of an element's voltage is based on how it is measured..

You don't need to go around a complete loop to form a correct KVL equation. You can journey between any two nodes, say from \$\phi_1\$ to \$\phi_2\$, and simply add the potential changes as you go. Starting at \$\phi_1\$, with potential \$V_{\phi 1}\$, adding and subtracting all the rises and falls in potential as you go to the right, when you reach \$\phi_2\$, the potential you have accumulated must equal \$V_{\phi 2}\$:
$$ V_{\phi 1} +V_{R1} + E_1 + V_{R2} + E_2 + V_{R3} + E_3 + E_4 + V_{R4} - E_5 = V_{\phi 2} $$
Notice that voltage source E5 has its positive terminal on the left, so as you traverse it to the right, you would encounter a fall in potential, hence the minus sign in front of it.
Also, remember that by passive sign convention, current is assumed to enter each resistor at its higher potential terminal, and leave the resistor from its lower potential end. Since I have treated each resistance as a rise in potential (adding each one), then current must be assumed to be flowing to the left, and should be labelled as such:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Once current direction has been labelled in conformity with resistor voltage polarities, you can proceed to apply Ohm's law:
$$ V_{\phi 1} + IR_1 + E_1 + IR_2 + E_2 + IR_3 + E_3 + E_4 + IR_4 - E_5 = V_{\phi 2} $$

You could, of course, have started at the right end, \$\phi_2\$, and travelled leftwards. If the direction of current is labelled (as above) as flowing to the left, then each resistor will represent a fall in potential instead. As you jump over each resistor from right to left, given that current enters its right end, its left end must have the lower potential. Your KVL equation must account for this:
$$ V_{\phi 2} + E_5 - IR_4 - E_4 - E_3 - IR_3 - E_2 - IR_2 - E_1 - IR_1 = V_{\phi 1} $$
Also notice that with the exception of E5, each voltage source is also treated as a fall in potential. This equation is still correct, and if you look carefully, you could re-arrange it to be exactly the same as the first KVL equation above. This is because I have been consistent with passive sign convention.

When current direction isn't labelled, and I don't know which direction current would actually flow, I still must label current direction one way or another, so that I can be consistent with passive sign convention. Below I've "guessed" that it flows to the right, instead:

simulate this circuit
Now each resistor's left end is assumed to have the higher potential, and represents a rise in potential as I traverse each resistor from right to left. Going from \$\phi_2\$ to \$\phi_1\$:
$$ V_{\phi 2} + E_5 + IR_4 - E_4 - E_3 + IR_3 - E_2 + IR_2 - E_1 + IR_1 = V_{\phi 1} $$
This is also valid, but in the final solution, you would find that current \$I\$ would have the opposite sign to \$I\$ found in the first two KVL equations above.

Thank you for answer and explanation. Sorry, is left terminal of E4 voltage source really positive on my figure? Maybe I don't understand

@ArturKrush Sorry, that should be E5. I'll correct that error.
