# KCL - Writing equation for essential node

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, kirchhoffs-laws

In this circuit there is a current source with value I. I got stuck at one point. We said that 'node b' is an 'essential node', and wrote the equation like this:

$$-i_1+i_2+i_6-I=0$$

But won't some of 'I' current go to the section where R7 is? Why do we take all current I for node b? The same for i6 too. Won't some of the i6 current go to the right? Why do we take only i6?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Because we treat it as one big node https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/333207/how-can-i-calculate-vs-in-this-circuit-knowing-vo-2/333214#333214

Comment: @G36 But in this link's example, https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVuDW.png equations like that and I5 included. So why there is no current for directly going left side? I don't understand that with that logic shouldn't be equation I1+I2+I3+I4=I6+I7?

Comment: For your circuit, we can write \$I_1 + I = I_2 + I_6\$ Because \$I1\$ and \$I\$ entering the node. And \$I_2\$ and \$I_6\$ are leaving the node.

Comment: @G36 But leaving current isn't bigger that i6 and entering current isn't lower than I? Because some of them leaves where the R7 is. Sorry if it's a silly question. (:.

Comment: How about now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mu1yd.png  Do you see that now \$I_1 + I = I_2 + I_6\$ And that the "whole" \$I\$ current entering the node b?

Comment: @G36 Thanks, I got it from this perspective. :). I didn't know we could think circuit like that.

Comment: Sure we can. We can treat this as one single (big) node. Just as I have shown here https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVuDW.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if you understand and agree on the selections of essential nodes (there's not only one set of choices) or if all you are trying to do is understand the three equations developed once they are chosen. I'm going to go with the idea, because of your other writing, that you want to understand the equations as given to you.

Let's look at each node, in isolation:

[image]

On left, you know that the sum of currents into the node must be equal to those leaving, so \$I+I_1=I_2+I_6\$. You can choose which side to move over to which side, but their choice was to move the left expression over to the right, so \$0=I_2+I_6-I-I_1\$.

In middle, find \$I_3+I_5=I_1\$. Here, they chose again to move the left expression over to the right, so \$0=I_1-I_3-I_5\$.

On right, find \$I_2=I_3+I_4\$. And again they chose to move the left expression over to the right, so \$0=I_3+I_4-I_2\$.

Now, there may be more questions. But I don't see where your confusion over the above may come from. It's straight-forward.

### Added re: ee_student's comment below (tl;dr)

ee-student made a comment below my answer here, which motivates me to write more. As I replied below, the idea of *essential nodes* is unnecessary. If you apply other ideas well, you wind up in similar places without imagining some mystery that you need to uncover because of a special phrase being used.

#### \$\quad\$ Simplify first

Let's draw out the schematic, again:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxg32W.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that I've chosen one of the nodes to be ground. You get to do that for exactly one node, but you also get to pick that node freely. So you might choose a different one. The one I picked allows me to pre-ordain **f**, **c**, and **a** as voltage sources with known values. And that's one of several ways to help clear out the rubbish.

Here's the newly redrawn, simplified schematic based upon that single ground assignment:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fp245R.png)</sup>

Note that there really **are** three nodes to worry about. They aren't the same ones you were provided in the answer you were given. But at least there are just three of them. So that matches up.

You could try to place the ground somewhere else and again redraw and simplify. You should, in fact. See if you wind up with three *essential* nodes, again. Then try it again. Etc.

I suppose one could call them *essential*. But this is over-thinking it. There isn't anything special about some particular three. It's just that the schematic inevitably works out to three unknown, *independent* node voltages. The others will either be a constant bias relative to ground or else a constant bias relative to one of the unknown independent node voltages.

Don't get it in mind that there is some mysterious concept you need to hammer into your head, which then magically allows you to identify and label *essential nodes*.

All we've done is apply a very general understanding about assigning ground to a node and then redrawing it.

You may have been given to believe that there's a mysterious skill you need to acquire. But if you apply the basic idea of just grounding a convenient node and then doing some redrawing, you'll find you don't really need to pursue the mystery further. It's not something new and it doesn't add anything to the prior art of KCL and/or KVL.

I'd prefer to avoid the phrase.

#### \$\quad\$ Just for fun

Now that we have the above, let's work out the behavioral KCL:

$$\begin{align*}
  \begin{array}{rccc}
  {\text{KCL for node }v_b:}\vphantom{I_2+I_6}\\\\
  {\text{KCL for node }v_e:}\vphantom{I_2+I_6}\\\\
  {\text{KCL for node }v_g:}\vphantom{I_2+I_6}
  \end{array}
&&
\overbrace{
 \begin{array}{r}
     I_2+I_6\\\\
     I_3+I_4\\\\
     I_5+I
 \end{array}
  }^{\text{outflowing currents}}
&
  \begin{array}{c}
  &\quad{=}\vphantom{I_2+I_6}\\\\
  &\quad{=}\vphantom{I_2+I_6}\\\\
  &\quad{=}\vphantom{I_2+I_6}
  \end{array}
&
\overbrace{
 \begin{array}{l}
      I_1+I\\\\
      I_2\\\\
      I_4+I_6
 \end{array}
  }^{\text{inflowing currents}}
\end{align*}$$

It just falls out easily.

It's not the same ones you were given. But then, the independent voltage nodes also aren't the same ones they chose, either.

It's not all that useful, yet, if we wanted to pursue a concrete solution. We've got six currents and only three equations. That may be good enough for classwork, if that's all that's being asked.

But we really only have three nodes, so we should only try to solve for those three node voltages when using KCL.

Let's just substitute in for the currents above using the obvious replacements to get a concrete set of KCL equations involving just the three independent unknown node voltages (and knowns/givens):

$$\begin{align*}
  \begin{array}{rccc}
  {\text{KCL for node }v_b:}\vphantom{\frac{\large{v}_b}{R_5}}\\\\
  {\text{KCL for node }v_e:}\vphantom{\frac{\large{v}_b}{R_5}}\\\\
  {\text{KCL for node }v_g:}\vphantom{\frac{\large{v}_b}{R_5}}
  \end{array}
&&
\overbrace{
 \begin{array}{r}
     \frac{{\large{v}}_b-{\large{v}}_e}{R_5}+\frac{{\large{v}}_b-{\large{v}}_g}{R_7}\\\\
     \frac{{\large{v}}_e-{\large{v}}_2}{R_2+R_4}+\frac{{\large{v}}_e-{\large{v}}_g}{R_6}\\\\
     \frac{{\large{v}}_g-0\:\text{V}}{R_4}+I
 \end{array}
  }^{\text{outflowing currents}}
&
  \begin{array}{c}
  &\quad{=}\vphantom{\frac{\large{v}_b}{R_5}}\\\\
  &\quad{=}\vphantom{\frac{\large{v}_b}{R_5}}\\\\
  &\quad{=}\vphantom{\frac{\large{v}_b}{R_5}}
  \end{array}
&
\overbrace{
 \begin{array}{l}
      \frac{\large{v}_1+\large{v}_2-{\large{v}}_b}{R_1}+I\\\\
      \frac{{\large{v}}_b-{\large{v}}_e}{R_5}\\\\
      \frac{{\large{v}}_e-{\large{v}}_g}{R_6}+\frac{{\large{v}}_b-{\large{v}}_g}{R_7}
 \end{array}
  }^{\text{inflowing currents}}
\end{align*}$$

And let's use a modern tool ([SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) -- no worrying over Cramer's rule for now) to solve this:

```
var('vb ve vg v1 v2 i r1 r2 r3 r4 r5 r6 r7')
eq1 = Eq( (vb-ve)/r5 + (vb-vg)/r7, (v1+v2-vb)/r1 + i )
eq2 = Eq( (ve-v2)/(r2+r4) + (ve-vg)/r6, (vb-ve)/r5 )
eq3 = Eq( (vg-0)/r4 + i, (ve-vg)/r6 + (vb-vg)/r7 )
ans = solve( [eq1, eq2, eq3], [vb, ve, vg] )
```

That's actually all you need to do.

But let's check it using a real simulator and stuffing in some values: \${\large{v}}_{_1}=5\:\text{V}\$, \${\large{v}}_{_2}=7\:\text{V}\$, \$R_1=15\:\Omega\$, \$R_2=6\:\Omega\$, \$R_3=3\:\Omega\$, \$R_4=10\:\Omega\$, \$R_5=20\:\Omega\$, \$R_6=4\:\Omega\$, \$R_7=5\:\Omega\$, and \$i=2\:\text{A}\$:

```
for r in ans:
    r, ans[r].subs( { v1:5, v2:7, r1:15, r2:6, r3:3, r4:10, r5:20, r6:4, r7:5, i:2 } ).n()
(vb, 11.3465346534653)
(ve, 4.93324816352603)
(vg, 2.73203449377196)
```

Now let's simulate:

[image]

Just as predicted. Nice.

#### \$\quad\$ So, don't worry

ee_student might do it differently (per comment below.) But I just wanted to make sure you realize that you already know what you need to know, without grasping after a false perception that there is a new idea you don't fully apprehend.

Everything is already there for you without a magic phrase. Just use concepts you've already learned about and move on.

Comment: Your answer explained it very clearly - I didn't know about the concept of an essential node. I just personally feel that those kinds of short cuts like selecting an essential node make it more confusing. If it was up to me, I'd give the short circuit branch between b and R7 its own current name, I(8) perhaps. And then the KCL is more straightforward.. (though there will be more equation overall).

Comment: @ee_student Good point. I'll add in the answer how I like to approach these because I, not so differently as you, also find that adding complexities such as *essential nodes* almost a guaranteed way to make mistakes no matter how good you get. It's just yet one more thing to keep in mind. I've worked all my life with some pretty good scientists. And if I would say one thing separating the better from the lesser of them, it would be that the better ones sought out and acquired the ***least*** number of the ***more general*** concepts and tossed out everything they were able to replace by them.

Comment: Very interesting point about the generalization skills required for science. Thanks..

Comment: @ee_student I've been fortunate, as much of my life has been blessed by actively working to solve novel problems in teams formed with some pretty good scientists with whom I worked very closely. If I could pick only one thing that separates the better of them, it would be that they **much more actively** sought out and acquired the **least number** of the **more general** concepts and **jettisoned from their minds** everything else that was replaceable by those more general mental tools.

Comment: @ee_student Would you rather learn one idea -- the concept of density formed by dividing mass by volume -- to help you address any situation you faced related to whether or not some solid object would sink or float in some liquid? Or would you prefer to learn that purified iron sinks in water, that certain rocks sink in water, that woods float in water (except that ebony sinks and then keep in mind there may yet be other woods that also sink), etc., etc? One rule? Or many narrow rules? Which is better? I know my answer to that.

Comment: @ee_student Even if this were the 1800's, where everything was paper and pencil and there were no helpful and freely available software, I'd still think retaining ideas which add no value should be chucked. Dump wasteful ideas which are already handled by the more powerful ones. Life is *way* too short and a brain that is cluttered up is a brain that cannot see the simple paths out of a problem because everything seems so complicated. You need to clear out the rubbish and keep the gems. (In these comments, I mean to use *you* in the English *plural you* form. Not you, specifically.)

Comment: Very good points & discussion. I'm not great at anything, but somehow I intuitively share this mindset. Everytime I'm offered a shortcut for a particular case, at the price that the shortcut requires of me to remember an arbitrary designation, I intuitively balk at such "shortcuts". Perhaps few "shortcuts" are genuinely valuable (& I'm missing on something), but for the most part, I also intuitively perceive these as more clutter than real value..

Comment: @ee_student I learned a hard lesson about this, one day when I met the one and only true super-genius of my lifetime. You know them. They simply aren't your species. They are something else, entirely. And you likely meet only one in your life, even if you travel in these circles. They are rare. He specialized in an entirely different area of physics and was visiting the physicist I was working with at the time (who was mundane by comparison.) I was at the chalkboard letting him ask me questions about what I had learned over the last year's time on a narrow subtopic within pyrometry.

Comment: @ee_student He would ask me about certain boundary cases. I'd answer. And in less than an hour's time he was fully abreast and was already leading the discussion into further areas that I'd intended on covering, but where I realized that I no longer need to do so. And soon enough, I was learning from him about my own topic. I was 35 then. This process floored me. So I asked him for more time. He and I just sat down and I interrogated his mind for as long as he allowed me. Since he was stuck there for the day, I got really lucky and had a few hours more to talk. It was brutal. But enlightening.

Answer (score 1):

Not it wont there is some current entering node b from the current source and there is some current leaving node b to R7.

Comment: Yes, but leaving current isn't bigger that i6 and entering current isn't lower than I?

Comment: No it doesnt work like that.In nodal or mesh analysis you just CANNOT  take into consideration only 1 source and forget about the rest of the circuit.In your example there are 2 currents flowing into the node and 2 currents flowing out of the node.